# no activity found to handle intent, android

Tags: java, android

I am getting the above error when I try and navigate to a link through my app, when I click on a listView item.

Can someone please advice me as to why this is happening?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.toString());
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

I am calling it like so:

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textview1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            Log.i("textview1",textview1.getText().toString().trim());
            TextView link = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.link);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.toString());
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));

            }
        });
```

LOGCAT:

```
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.widget.TextView{42fc3c40 V.ED.... ...P.... 0,327-1080,620 #7f050044 app:id/link} }
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1671)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3661)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3629)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at com.example.rssapplication.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:80)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-17 11:23:46.608: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your error from logcat.

Comment: what is the value of link and does that activity exists?

Comment: I have added the logcat, and also how I am calling it

Comment: Did you add Internet permission in menifest.?

Comment: Yes the internet permission is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this to get the text from the EditText : `link.toString();`

To get text from the edit text : `String url = link.getText().toString();`

To open the link :

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `link` you used, but I think that you forgot to add the schema. If it's like `www.google.com` replace it with `http://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `link.toString()` into the `URI`. Instead of this you need to pass `link.getText().toString()`.

See The edited line in your code.

I just replace

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.toString());
```

to

`Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.getText().toString().trim());`

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Log.i("textview1",textview1.getText().toString().trim());
        TextView link = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.link);

        //Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.toString()); // WRONG STATEMENT
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.getText().toString().trim()); // EDITED
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));

        }
    });
```